# Why the FileVersion and AssemblyVersion is expanded to 4 digits?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I am using `.Net Core 2.2` and for my project, I am applying the versioning of 3 digit. I have added line in my `csproj` file:

```
<Version>$(BuildNumber)</Version>
```

And I am passing version while performing `dotnet publish` i.e.

```
dotnet publish myproject.csproj /p:BuildNumber=1.0.3.
```

However I have observed that the product version of my DLL is 1.0.3 but the file version is 1.0.3.0.
Does anyone know how to keep the file version same as product version?

Comment: File version is a Windows version number (`System.Version`) which is always a four-part number.

Comment: Ok so there is no way to override that right? 
I mean to make it of 3 digit.